# How can an autoencoder unroll the swiss roll?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders

I'm trying to unroll the [swiss roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction#/media/File:Lle_hlle_swissroll.png) (from 3D to 2D) using an autoencoder, but it keeps getting stuck in local optima: the swiss roll ends up squashed rather than unrolled. It's no better than using PCA, basically.

If I just have one hidden layer with 2 units, the autoencoder just projects the swiss roll down to 2D, which squashes it (like PCA), and the decoder can't recover the unrolled version. So I tried to stack 3 hidden layers like so:

```
ouputs    (3 units)    \
  |                     | decoder
hidden 3  (5 units)     |
  |                    /
hidden 2  (2 units)    \
  |                     | encoder
hidden 1  (5 units)     |
  |                    /
inputs    (3D)
```

But for some reason this does not work any better. Since I'm pretty sure the weights could be set manually to make it work fine, I guess this means that training is stuck in a local minimum.

I have tried tying the weights ($W_{out} = {W_1}^T$, and $W_3 = {W_2}^T$) and adding $\ell_2$ regularization, but to no avail.

Any idea on what I should try next?

**Edit**

- I'm using the ELU activation function in all hidden layers, and no activation function in the output layer.
- I've successfully used this same architecture (with more neurons) to compress MNIST, so it works fine with more dimensions.

Comment: You could start with the 2D case, which might allow easier visualization? (like [here](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#dataset=spiral))

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Wow, what a cool link.

Comment: @amoeba Good point, I updated my question.  I'm using ELU for all hidden layers (I tried ReLU as well) and no activation function for the output layer.

Comment: what is the your overall goal?  it probably is local minima, but do you want to get this working or just try different method? basically swiss roll is 'easy' for locally linear models and hard for 'global' models such as MLP autoencoders

Comment: @seanv507 Interesting, thanks.  I'm mostly trying to get more experience on autoencoders, there's no other overall goal for now. It seems weird that I can train neural nets to recognize cats on pictures, but I can't unroll a simple swiss roll...  :/

Comment: @seanv507 I'm investigating locally-constrained sparse autoencoders, perhaps they can do the trick: https://goo.gl/12cJ3V

Comment: I *believe* the image recognition problems where NNs have had most success are actually quite linear (https://github.com/ducha-aiki/caffenet-benchmark/blob/master/Activations.md the linear model has 39% accuracy vs 52% for best non linear activation).   Maybe you could just plot the error curve in a few random directions for MNIST vs swiss roll to see whether that highlights 'local minima'.

Comment: @seanv507 +1 Great insights, thanks a lot Sean.

Comment: @seanv507, I found a solution I really like: diffusion nets (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07840.pdf).  More generally, (1) create a representative sample of the dataset, (2) use diffusion maps (or LLE or any other algo) to create the embedding (3) train the encoder so it learns that embedding, (4) train a decoder to learn the reverse mapping, (5) create the autoencoder from the pair.

Comment: Did you try increasing the size of intermediate layers from 5 to something higher, e.g. 10?

Comment: @seanv507: Hmm. The model with 39% uses max pooling, can we still call it "linear"? Apart from that, 52% is quite low, I thought best NNs show much better results on ImageNet. Why the difference?

Comment: @amoeba -agreed it is nonlinear through max pooling but this is fixed. In the associated paper (fig 1)- the best net is ~72% using VGGNet and 227x227 input image. The network investigated uses a smaller input image (128x128) and fewer parameters allowing each training experiment to be done in a day vs a month. paper is linked from here https://github.com/ducha-aiki/caffenet-benchmark